# Problem with using package \usepackage{amsmath}

Tags: amsmath, compilation-error

For my thesis I want to use the *amsmath* package, but when I import it into my settings.sty file I get more than 100 error. I have already read that I should import it before hyperref, but errors are still there. Maybe somebody can help me out here?

The important part of my settings file looks like this:

```
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\graphicspath{ {images/} } %seeting the path for all images 
\usepackage{tocbibind} 
\usepackage[german]{babel} 
\usepackage{titlesec} 
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{float} 
\usepackage{setspace} 
\usepackage{ragged2e} 
\usepackage{mathptmx} 
\usepackage{tikz} 
\usetikzlibrary{positioning,shapes.multipart,shapes, calc} 
\usepackage{caption} 
\usepackage[a4paper, left=3cm, right=2.5cm, top=2.5cm, bottom=2cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{acro} 
\usepackage{array} 
\usepackage{longtable} 
\usepackage{supertabular} 
\usepackage{amsmath} %HERE IS THE PACKAGE CAUSING PROBLEM!
\usepackage{hyperref} 
\hypersetup{
    colorlinks,
    citecolor=black,
    filecolor=black,
    linkcolor=black,
    urlcolor=black } 
\usepackage{cleveref}

\usepackage{fancyhdr}

\usepackage{csquotes} 
\usepackage[
    backend=biber,
    style=numeric,
    citestyle=numeric,
    abbreviate=false, 
    autocite=footnote,
    maxcitenames=3 
]{biblatex} 
\addbibresource{literatur.bib} 
\DeclareNameAlias{default}{family-given/given-family} 
\DeclareLanguageMapping{german}{german-apa} 
\renewcommand*{\multinamedelim}{\addcomma\space} 
\renewcommand*{\finalnamedelim}{\addspace\bibstring{and}\addspace}

\usepackage{tocloft}

%settings for image in right top corner 
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc} 
\usepackage{eso-pic} 
\newcommand\AtPageUpperRight[1]{\AtPageUpperLeft{%   
\makebox[\paperwidth][r]{#1}}}    
\usepackage{chngcntr} 

\counterwithin{figure}{section} 
\counterwithin{table}{section}

%------------  Text Environment  --------------------
\newenvironment{text}
{
    \begin{justify}
    \begin{spacing}{1.2}
}{
    \end{spacing}
    \end{justify}
}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\renewcommand\lstlistingname{Quellcode}
\renewcommand\lstlistlistingname{Quellcodeverzeichnis}
\endinput
```

My main.tex looks like this:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{settings}
\title{\textbf{Titel}}
\date{}
\begin{document}
\author{}

\section{Section}
\begin{text}
This is some text where I am using equation
\end{text}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX SX! Could you please post a complete compilable code? We don't know you document class and there's no  main body reproducing your problem.

Comment: thanks for your answer. I added some content to the question. Hopefully that's all you need

Comment: you should provide an example that shows the error, and show exactly the (first) error reported in the log.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first error I see is from the bare `\includegraphics`.  I'm not sure what you're trying with that.

The amsmath error is because amsmath defines a `\text` command, but so does your `\newenvironment{text}`.  You're going to need to change your environment's name if you want amsmath.

Comment: sorry, that \includegraphics was some copy mistake from my side. Changing my \text command worked

Comment: @Henning why do you want that environment at all? `\begin{justify}` does nothing useful, as justification is the defaut.

Comment: I am not very used to Tex. Just saw this on the internet to set the spacing. Can I do it more easily?

Comment: It will mainly depend on how much you want to have 1.2 spacing, and how much you want to have the default spacing.  If the entire document should be 1.2, that's easy enough to set in the preamble.  If you're wanting to switch back and forth, then you'll probably want an environment.  But then the question would be why you're wanting to switch.  (TeX is notorious for leading to long preambles that get copy/pasted around.  Some would argue that you'll be better served by deleting all of it and starting your own preamble from scratch.)

Comment: To add to the last comment, if you want the whole document to be spaced at 1.25 then you can load `\usepackage[onehalfspacing]{setspace}`. If you want just certain parts then you can use the `{spacing}` environment just for those parts. Also, I agree with the comment about starting with a minimal preamble and only add what is really needed.

Comment: Thank you all for your kind answers. 
I got some good solution now with package setspace.

Answer (score 3):

The error generated is

```
! LaTeX Error: Missing \begin{document}.

See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              
                                                  
l.3 \includegraphics
```

because  the spurious `includegraphics` on line 3 of `settings.sty` which should be deleted.

If that is deleted you get

```
! LaTeX Error: Command \text already defined.
               Or name \end... illegal, see p.192 of the manual.

See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              
                                                  
l.68 }
      
?
```

as you are over-writing the standard `\text` command